# ffmpeg stream breaks after 5 min

Tags: python, ffmpeg

ffmpeg stream breaks after 5 min on ubuntu server when i run python!
But when I run bash- it works fine:
ffmpeg -re -nostdin -i /root/app2/m4.avi -vcodec libx264 -preset:v medium -bufsize 200000k -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/live
I tried to edit the bufsize - but this didnt work. May be the problem is to connect reset after time.

My python script:
import time
import subprocess
import os

if **name** == "**main**":

```
    file = '/root/app2/m4.avi'

    command = []
    command.extend([
        'ffmpeg',
        '-re',
        '-nostdin',
        '-i', file,
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-preset:v', 'medium',
        '-b:v', '3000k','-maxrate', '10000k','-bufsize', '200000k',
        '-acodec', 'aac',
        '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/live______',
    ])

    #' '.join(command)

    process = subprocess.Popen(command,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    st=time.time()
    while time.time()-st<100*60:
        print(time.time()-st)
```

Comment: Does ffmpeg even get executed? Is the problem with the python code or ffmpeg? Does ffmpeg show any errors? The log from ffmpeg would be helpful.

Comment: Now, mmpeg works good, within python it doesnot launch